# GitHubで本名とハンドルネームを使い分けたい

Tags: github

事情により本名での活動が必要になりましたが、
GitHub上ではハンドルネームで登録していて
なんとかして本名と関連付けられないようにしたいです。

本名とハンドルネームを使い分けるいい手段はないでしょうか?
複数アカウント以外でお願いします。だめなので。
課金がいるものも控えてください。

Comment: 具体的にどのような状態になれば満足なのでしょうか？単一GitHubアカウントを使う時点で、2つの名前が同一人物と推測されるのは避けられないのでは？

Comment: GitHub上でのOrganizationに属する人に対しては本名、そうでない人にはハンドルネームを使い、他の人にはOrganizationに属することも伏せたい、程度です。

Comment: コミット単位で見かけ上のユーザー名は任意に変更できますが、単一のGitHubアカウント(メールアドレス)を使う限り、他方に秘匿しながらの使い分けは少なくとも無料版の範囲では難しいと思います。

Comment: わかりました。GitHub側に問い合わせます。

Comment: 個人的には、複数アカウントの使い分けが、一番現実解なような気がしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました:どうやらOrganizationの所属ってPrivateにできるようですね。
ありがとうございます。